# Best practice to initialize ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, init

I have an ajax call wrapped into a function in order to do polling which is

```
function doPoll(){
        alert('GO POLL')
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                'method':'POST',
                'url':'/ajax/request_news',
                'beforeSend':function(){
                    alert('Before send')
                    date = new Date()
                    var timestamp_last_check = Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000)
                },
                'data':{'last_check':timestamp_last_check}, 
                'success':function(ret){
                    ret = $.parseJSON(ret)
                },
                'complete':function(){
                    doPoll()
                }

            })
       },5000)
    };
```

This request doesn't work because it says that the var timestamp_last_check is not initialized. I though that putting this in `beforeSend` would work but it seems that the data context is retrieved before the `beforeSend` call.

I can't put my timestamp initialization outside the AJAX call because there's the `setTimeout` who will cause a 5 seconds delay between the initialization of the timestamp and the AJAX call.

I saw that there's a `$.ajaxSetup` function but the doc recommend not to use it.

What's the best practice to initialize this `timestamp_last_check` var ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
setTimeout(function () {
     var timestamp_last_check = 0; //declare here to make it available to data:
     $.ajax({
         'method': 'POST',
             'url': '/ajax/request_news',
             'beforeSend': function () {
             alert('Before send')
             date = new Date()
             timestamp_last_check = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000); //set Value here
         },
```

---

**Problem**

`var timestamp_last_check` is local to the `beforeSend:` only so it is not accessible outside the block.

```
'beforeSend': function () {
                 alert('Before send')
                 date = new Date()
                 var timestamp_last_check = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000)
             },
```

Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

---

Updated After OP's comment

```
function doPoll() {
    alert('GO POLL');
    setTimeout(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var timestamp_last_check = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);//set value here
        $.ajax({
            'method': 'POST',
                'url': '/ajax/request_news',
                'data': {
                'last_check': timestamp_last_check
            },
                'success': function (ret) {
                ret = $.parseJSON(ret)
            },
                'complete': function () {
                doPoll()
            }
        })
    }, 5000)
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working. The value sent to the server is 0

Comment: It worked, thanks :) Too bad that there's not an inner AJAX function to initialize the data, it would be 'cleaner'

Comment: @Kobz You can change the data within beforeSend. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
function doPoll() {
    alert('GO POLL')
    var timestamp_last_check;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': '/ajax/request_news',
            'beforeSend': function (xhr, settings) {
                alert('Before send')
                date = new Date()
                timestamp_last_check = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
                settings.data.last_check = timestamp_last_check;
            },
            'success': function (ret) {
                ret = $.parseJSON(ret)
            },
            'complete': function () {
                doPoll()
            }

        })
    }, 5000)
};
```

Notice that I have declared timestamp_last_check in the scope of doPoll method. This makes it closure for the beforeSend. And the [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) accepts two arguments. The second argument is the settings object which should be used to change the settings or add any data in the request.

Comment: It also worked, so the data is accessible by `settings.data`, good to know !